# Output parameter returns zero while stored procedure returns affected rows count

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, sqlclient, idatareader

I am doing a user registration page. Inserting user stored procedure is working perfectly and in SQL Server and Profile viewer, output parameter returns `@@Rowcount`, while calling this stored procedure from C#, it always return "0".

My stored procedure is like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [CM].[usp_InsertUser] 
    @pEncrUserId            NVARCHAR(max),
    @pApplicationTypeId     BIGINT,
    @pLanguageId            BIGINT,
    @pUsername              VARCHAR(15),
    @pPassword              NVARCHAR(max),
    @pRecoverEmail          VARCHAR(128),   
    @pCreatedBy             BIGINT,
    @pReturnId              INT OUTPUT ,
    @pErrorMessage          NVARCHAR(Max) OUTPUT    
AS
BEGIN TRY     
    INSERT INTO [CM].[tb_ApplicationUser] ([EncrUserId], [ApplicationTypeId],[LanguageId], 
                                           [UserName], [UserPassword], [RecoverEmail], 
                                           [CreatedBy], [StatusId], [ConcurId])
    VALUES (@pEncrUserId, @pApplicationTypeId, @pLanguageId,
            @pUsername, @pPassword, @pRecoverEmail,
            @pCreatedBy, 1, NEWID())

    SET @pReturnId = @@ROWCOUNT 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @pReturnID = @@ERROR;
    SET @pErrorMessage  = ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH
```

And my C# code:

```
cmd = dbClient.GetCommand("cm.usp_InsertUser", CommandType.StoredProcedure);

dbClient.AddParameter(cmd, "@pEncrUserId", DALayer.EnumEx.DBDataTypes.NVarChar, ParameterDirection.Input, 0, objInput.EncrUseId);
dbClient.AddParameter(cmd, "@pApplicationTypeId", DALayer.EnumEx.DBDataTypes.BigInt, ParameterDirection.Input, 150, objInput.ApplicationtypeId);
dbClient.AddParameter(cmd, "@pLanguageId", DALayer.EnumEx.DBDataTypes.BigInt, ParameterDirection.Input, 150, objInput.LanguageId);
dbClient.AddParameter(cmd, "@pUsername", DALayer.EnumEx.DBDataTypes.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Input, 15, objInput.UserName);
dbClient.AddParameter(cmd, "@pPassword", DALayer.EnumEx.DBDataTypes.NVarChar, ParameterDirection.Input, 0, objInput.Password);
dbClient.AddParameter(cmd, "@pRecoverEmail", DALayer.EnumEx.DBDataTypes.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Input, 150, objInput.RecoverEmail);
dbClient.AddParameter(cmd, "@pCreatedBy", DALayer.EnumEx.DBDataTypes.BigInt, ParameterDirection.Input, 150, objInput.CreatedBy);
dbClient.AddParameter(cmd, "@pReturnId", DALayer.EnumEx.DBDataTypes.BigInt, ParameterDirection.Output, 150);
dbClient.AddParameter(cmd, "@pErrorMessage", DALayer.EnumEx.DBDataTypes.NVarChar, ParameterDirection.Output, 150);

IDataReader dsTemp = dbClient.ExecuteDataReader(cmd);

returnID = Convert.ToInt64(dbClient.GetParameterValue(cmd, "@pReturnId"));
```

Any advice is helpful for me. I can't understand whats the wrong in this. This method is working in other insertions of project.

Comment: Why not use [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) instead? It will return affected rows count.

Comment: You need to debug `GetParameterValue` method.

Comment: Probably won't make a difference but you're declaring it `int` in the SQL and `bigint` in the C# code.

Comment: Does you table have a Primary Key?  You are using INSERT and if the row already exists with the same Primary Key you will get a return of zero since no rows were changed.  Insert will not change a row.  You will then need to use Update.

Comment: What is `dbClient`? Why not do a `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` and read the resulting output?

Comment: @jdweng I am using another SP for getting sequenceId while pass the table name, and insert that value as a primary key. That makes the issue and I comment that line and it perfectly return in code side.

Comment: @Flater dbClient is a helper class in  DAL.

Comment: ExecuteDataReader gets an enumerator.  You then have to use the Read() to get the data.  See msdn for example : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for contributing your valuable knowledge and time.

I found the reason why it returns 0, I am using another SP to generate sequenceId ( that is not mentioned in this question) and pass that value as a primary key in this [CM].[tb_ApplicationUser] table. when I comment that line and passed some value into [CM].[tb_ApplicationUser] table. So it returns @@Rowcount or whatever the value perfectly in,

`returnID = Convert.ToInt64(dbClient.GetParameterValue(cmd, "@pReturnId"));`

In this case I understand multiple DML attempt may makes the problem for getting @@ROWCOUNT. DML query will work fine and it will affect the table, but we cannot get the desired output in Code side (ExecuteDataReader or else).